# C# Restore size of Form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, resize, mdichild

I have `ovveride` the event `onResize` for MDI Child `Form`, this is the code:

```
protected override void OnResize(EventArgs e)
{
    base.OnResize(e);
    if (WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized)
    {
        WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        Height = MdiParent.ClientSize.Height - 70;
        Width = MdiParent.ClientSize.Width - 10;
        Location = new Point(0, 0);
    }
}
```

When user click the button `Maximize` on the `Form`, i will set a "standard" Size.
So it's look somenthing like this

[image: Resize of the Form]

How can i change the button `Maximize` to `Restore`since it has reached its maximum size set by me?

Comment: You can't. The restore button will only show if your form WindowState == FormWindowState.Maximized. You are setting it back to FormWindowState.Normal in your handler.

Comment: @aschoenebeck - I set it to `FormWindowState.Normal` because otherwise the menu of MDI Child Form intersects with that of the `Parent`

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to achieve a responsive Windows application:

1. try to use use split container panel (for info, [MSDN Info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.splitcontainer(v=vs.110).aspx))
2. by using Anchor ([YouTube link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tlht6urrb5A))
3. using this following code

   ```
               private Size oldSize;

               protected override void OnResize(System.EventArgs e)
               {
                   base.OnResize(e);
                   foreach (Control cnt in this.Controls)
                   {
                       ResizeAll(cnt, base.Size);
                   }

                   oldSize = base.Size;
               }

               private void ResizeAll(Control cnt, Size newSize)
               {
                   int iWidth = newSize.Width - oldSize.Width;

                   cnt.Left += (cnt.Left * iWidth) / oldSize.Width;
                   cnt.Width += (cnt.Width * iWidth) / oldSize.Width;            
                   int iHeight = newSize.Height - oldSize.Height;
                   cnt.Top += (cnt.Top * iHeight) / oldSize.Height;
                   cnt.Height += (cnt.Height * iHeight) / oldSize.Height;
               }
   ```

call this event on windows form-resize event.

Comment: It's not what I asked